# React Navigation v3 not working under Expo

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am using [expo](https://expo.io/) to manage my React Native app. When I want to load it on my Android device I am using their app from the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=host.exp.exponent&hl=en). Everything was going perfectly fine until earlier today (01.10) when the client app on my Android device got automatically updated from Play Store.

**What was the issue?**

*The issue is that my code base is using Expo SDK 32.0 but the latest Android client app requires at least version 33.0 of your Expo SDK.*

What I did was to follow this guide: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/#sdk-33

It all went well ... but not really. I had some serious issues with some of my packages and things got really messed up.

**So, what I decided to do next?**

I have a very important demo this week and I don't have the time to investigate integration issues First, I reverted my code base to what it was (Expo SDK 32.0) and then I decided to remove the client app from my Android device and install a previous version of it by downloading this APK: https://apkpure.com/expo/host.exp.exponent/download/103-APK

Now, I can load the application on the device but I am getting very strange errors related to my navigation:

```
TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'theme.label')

This error is located at:
    in HeaderTitle (at Header.tsx:220)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Header.tsx:531)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at react-native-safe-area-view/index.js:163)
    in SafeView (at withOrientation.js:54)
    in withOrientation (at Header.tsx:722)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Header.tsx:714)
    in Header (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackViewLayout.tsx:227)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.tsx:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:59)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.tsx:93)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.tsx:95)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.tsx:985)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.tsx:394)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.tsx:384)
    in Handler (at StackViewLayout.tsx:377)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.tsx:104)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.tsx:41)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:80)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createAppContainer.js:430)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:97)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:22)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:21)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:97)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:22)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:21)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
```

The way I've implemented my navigation is as follows:

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

// .. other imports

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    // screen definitions
});

export default createAppContainer(StackNavigator);
```

I don't really understand where is this error coming from and how I could fix it.

**More info:**

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.57.1
- expo: 2.6.14
- expo skd: 32.0

I will also share my **package.json**:

```
{
...
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "firebase": "^5.8.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
...
}
```

and, of course **app.json**:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "qr-scanner",
    "slug": "qr-scanner",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "landscape",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

The error occurs right after I selected an option on the device which is supposed to change the screen. Then the navigation gets involved and I am getting this error.

Comment: are you using a lockfile? it seems like there are mismatched versions of react-navigation packages here. try installing `react-navigation@3.13.0` explicitly

Comment: Can you test the in snack example: https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/hello-react-navigation-v3

Comment: @brentvatne after doing that I am now getting this error: Unable to resolve "./touchables" from "node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\index.js"

Comment: @brentvatne And also, when I do `npm list react-native-gesture-handler` in my project folder I am getting `react-native-gesture-handler@1.0.12`

Comment: the snack you shared is on sdk34, and from sdk34 onward it's necessary for developers to install dependencies like react-native-gesture-handler explicitly rather than depending on them being installed by the expo package. if you can share a link to your project on github i could help further

Comment: @brentvatne But how did you decide it is using sdk34? I haven't posted any snack. It is just to code from the question. Our repo is private and it will be hard to share it.

Answer (score 0):

Expo released SDK 35 not too long ago, and as you know they drop support for old SDK's (in this case it is SDK 31 and SDK 32).

Okay, looking at your package.json file i dont see a problem - infact i recommend you to upgrade to SDK 35, you can read all about it [here](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-35-is-now-available-beee0dfafbf4)

In regards to your issue, lets proceed by upgrading and to save you time do as follows:

1. Make sure you are not running your project or the epxo cli active.
2. Edit your `app.json` by changing sdkVersion to `35.0.0`
3. Edit your `package.json` as follows:

   - `react-native` to `https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz`
   - `expo` to `^35.0.0`
   - `react` to `16.8.3`
   - `react-navigation` to `^4.0.6`
4. run `expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-navigation`
5. Delete your `node_modules` directory then run `npm install` or `yarn install`
6. Run expo start -c

**Now you can use `expo install` to install any expo dependencies needed instead of the old `npm install` it will download a compatible dependency for your project**

Hope this Helps!